# Masked html redirect to php stays unmasked

Tags: php, html, redirect

I'm redirecting from HTML site A to PHP site B, redirect works fine but the URL from site B is IP:PORT and I want to keep the URL from Site A.

Tried several options I found googling for 'mask redirect' like frames and Iframes but the IP:PORT for site B always shows after the redirect, so redirect works, but masking does not.

I tested a redirect from same HTML site A to HTML site C and both redirect and mask work exactly as I want it to.

Tried several options in .htaccess on site B (not knowing exactly how to) but all attempts lead to a Server error.

Site B runs under Windows/Apache, it's an open source cloud service including the Apache install so I'm bound to use this combination.

Seems like an Apache PHP issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

If www.siteA.com and www.siteB.com are on different hosts, the only way to get the content on www.siteB.com to be served while the browser's URL address bar says www.siteA.com is to request the content on behalf of the browser.

You can do this either by setting up a proxy using apache or maybe an iframe.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
  <head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {margin:0;}
      iframe { padding:0; border:0; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; }
    </style>
   </head>    
   <body>
     <iframe src="http://www.example.com/"></iframe>
   </body>
 </html>
```

If using apache, you'd need access to your vhost config for the www.siteA.com domain:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^(.*)$ http://www.siteB.com$1
```

Take a look at the mod_proxy docs for more info on the flags you can pass this directive, to tweak timeouts and retries.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

If you want to setup a php script to proxy, do so in your .htaccess file in your www.siteA.com document root, add (assuming this php script is called redirect_proxy.php):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect_proxy.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect_proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in redirect_proxy.php, look for the url query string, load that page, and output it to the browser.

Comment: Sorry man, I know you're trying to help but I dont get it.

What you dont know: I have several domains and subdomains on site A and I only want to redirect subdomain X. Normally I work with HTML but I'm forced into the PHP corner now. However, there are no files under subdomain X except for one empty php page and HTML pages I just created under public_html. They work.

Not sure where to put redirect_proxy.php or proxy.php.

Also not sure if I should mess with the vhost config IF I can find it.

Starting with that one PHP file, can you guide me?
I can understand if you think it's hopeless ;-)

Comment: You can do the same with a sub-domain. change www.siteA.com to sub.siteA.com and point it to the url you want. I gave you 3 solutions, you don't need to do them all. If the iframe doesn't work than try just putting a .htaccess file at the root of the subdomain and use the above rewrite rule. Honestly if I were you I'd be doing this type of thing at the DNS level, url-forwarding with mask via DNS is simple and easy to do.

Comment: Cant do this with DNS because it does not accept a portnumber.
Cannot reroute the standart port because thats rerouted to IIS sites.
.htaccess approach does not work either and I dont understand the rest of your instructions because lack of detail.
Thanks for your time, I give up.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly, I believe browser developers go to great lengths in an attempt to prevent this sort of thing, so that people cannot pretend to be someone they are not.

If you are in control of both sites, and these sorts of moral/legal issues have no bearing - have you considered a large iFrame on site A to contain all of site B? The iFrame could be in a display: none div, or hidden in some other way, then when it's time for the "redirect", you could show the div with the iframe, hide the other content if necessary, and change the url of the iFrame via javascript (or have it already loaded via the original src attribute of the iframe).

Alternatively you could grab the data in an ajax call and pop it into the innerHTML of an existing element on your page.

Comment: I assure you that both servers are rented by me, there's nothing illegal or obscure. I only want to present my future customers with one url to connect to and hide the ugly IP:PORT combination.

Comment: And again, as I wrote, I tried frame and iframe. I'm not familiar with Ajax but as I also wrote that if I redirect to another of my HTML sites the masking does work, so it almost HAS to be caused by some Apache setting or PHP code on site B.

Comment: You did mention that you tried an iframe, but I'm curious, are you still redirecting your site? Instead of redirecting your site, change the src attribute of the iframe.

Comment: Yes after redirecting I also tried the src attribute. In fact, before I responded I tried your code.